# сравнить элементы массива с рандомным числом

Tags: javascript

Всем здравствуйте. Нужна рекрусивная функция t1. С ее помощью необходимо сравнить элементы массива с рандомным числом от 0 до 10. Если число уже есть - выполняет генерацию заново. Если нет - возвращает это число. Не хватает рекурсива.

```
function randNum(min, max) {
    let rand = min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min);
    return Math.floor(rand);
}
let arr = [3, 4, 6, 7, 8];

function t1() {
    let m = randNum(0, 10)
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] !== m) return m
      else return t1()
    }
 }
console.log(t1())
```

Comment: А какой у вас собственно вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос, как использовать рекурсию.

Comment: если надо с помощью рекурсивной функции сравнивть число с элементом массива, то функция должна принимать на вход индекс элемента, и при рекурсивном вызове увеличивать его на 1.

Comment: доходя до конца массива возвращайте `false`, а на 0-м уровне проверяйте результат, если false, то перегенерация и по новой. то есть на 0 уровне должен быть цикл

Comment: спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать...

Comment: а вы в курсе, что у вас цикл всегда проходит только 1 итерацию?

Comment: догадываюсь, а из-за чего так происходит??

Comment: потому что во время итерации вы либо заново запускаете функцию, либо возвращаете число.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const numbers = [3, 4, 6, 7, 8];

const generateRandomInt = (min, max) => {
    return Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min));
};

const getInclusiveNumber = (compareNumbers) => {
    const number = generateRandomInt(0, 10);

    const isNotInclusive = compareNumbers.includes(number);

    if (isNotInclusive) {
        return getInclusiveNumber(compareNumbers);
    }
    return number;
};

console.log(getInclusiveNumber(numbers));
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Только не много не понятно: почему const isNotInclusive = compareNumbers.includes(number)    а не const isNotInclusive = numbers.includes(number)??     compareNumbers - это разве массив?

Comment: @Shavor https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: Все правильно. Разобрался) Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: @Shavor лучшим спасибо будет отметка о решении

Comment: подскажите, как это сделать...

Comment: @Shavor галочка слева от ответа